# Problems when invoking a system command in RStudio

Tags: r, shell, rstudio

I'm trying to run an `exe` file by invoking a system command through R's IDE RStudio. My OS is Windows.

I have the following hierarchy for directories:

```
|_scripts
|_files
  |_prog.exe
|_data
  |_executed_data
    |_case1
    |_case2
```

My `exe` file is stored at the `files` directory. The wrangled, ready-to-use data are stored in specific `case#` directories, where # represents the respective number for that case.

The code is modular. I write functions and then use `purrr::map` to iterate that function over a vector of the same length as the number of cases.

Here's how the code looks:

```
#Library(processx)
#Library(purrr)

run_exe = function(directory) {

  # Copy .exe file to folder to run
  from_dir = c("../files/prog.exe")
  to_dir = paste0("../data/executed_data/", directory)

  file.copy(from = from_dir,  to = to_dir, overwrite = T)

  # Run .exe file
  processx::run( command = paste0("../data/executed_data/",directory,"/prog.exe" )
}

# Run function over all cases
all_cases = list.files("../data/executed_data")
purrr::map(all_cases, run_exe)
```

The attempt to run with `map` fails and a message of error is printed to the console. The printed message says one of the subroutines of the `exe` file can't find a specific file, hence, the error.

I noticed that the supposed missing file has its name printed in lower case so I renamed the file to make sure all letters were small. Still, it didn't work.

The message also says an `error.err` file has been printed. This file does get printed when an error happens, however, if I go directly to one of the `cases#` directory and double click on the `exe` file, it runs with no problem. Since it runs with no problem, I know there's no missing file.

Given this question deals with running an `exe` file, I didn't think a reproducible example would be possible. If, however, you have had similar issues when trying to invoke a system function, please share the solution you found.

P.S.: Before using processx::run, I toyed with the `system`, `system2`, and `sys` functions but, again, no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
# List all directory paths. These are the directories where data are stored.
all_dir = dir(here::here('data', 'executed_data'), full.names = TRUE)

# Function to process all your data. Note the arg "wd"
process_data = function (data_dir) {
    processx::run(here::here('files', 'prog.exe'), wd = data_dir)
}

# Iterate over all directories
purrr::map(.x = all_dir, .f = process_data)
```

It's important to have the `.Rproj` at the same level as directories `scripts`, `files`, `data`.